# Open-source проекты на Java, с наилучшей архитектурой

Tags: java, ооп, архитектура

Очень хочется увидеть открытые проекты на Java (средние или крупные), которые бы соответствовали по-максимуму всем принципам разработки ПО - с наиболее верной архитектурой, наиболее правильным ООП,разделением кода, и т.д. Тяжело все время копаться в чужом коде, который, как правило, далек от этого. Идеал конечно на ищу - но хотя бы несколько проектов, которые, по Вашему мнению, наиболее правильные в данном отношении. Очень нужен образец, который можно показать как руководству, так и самому порадоваться.

Надеюсь, что вопрос не будет расценен как холивар. Возможно есть какие-то открытые проекты, в которых принимали участие сами авторы принципов ООП/паттернов и т.д.? Или может уже кто-то задавался этим вопросом ранее и есть готовые оценки открытых проектов? Здесь нет, конечно, однозначного ответа - но не понимаю как его иначе еще можно сформулировать.

Comment: могу просто на большие проекты указать, как там внутри с архитектурой решать не мне

Comment: вот например https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community

Comment: https://github.com/gaeaplus/gaeaplus

Comment: Вопрос субъективный и поэтому не подходит для SO. По поводу участия известных авторов, посмотрите на [JUnit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5). Первая версия была написана Кентом Беком (создатель [XP](http://tiny.cc/3btx7y)) и Эрихом Гаммой (один из авторов [Design Patterns](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)) во время полета в самолете. Библиотека относительно небольшая, в ней реально разобраться, и служит образцом хорошо покрытого тестами кода. Не думаю, впрочем, что в ней Вы встретите много паттернов, т.к. не все они там нужны.

Comment: JUnit да - мне на другом ресурсе его же посоветовали. Значит точно надо посмотреть.  Как лучше переформулировать вопрос? не могу просто придумать - ведь многие понимают о чем спрашиваю наверняка. Про субъективность тоже странно на самом деле - ведь есть же критерии поддерживаемости. модульности, тестируемости и т.д. Пусть не будет точной оценки - но ведь плохой код детектируется достаточно однозначно?

Comment: Есть же вопросы про список книг - почему не может быть вопроса про список хороших проектов?